# Application tried to present modally an active controller error in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've found some other posts concerning this issue, but none of those suggestion really helped me. I understand that in the new iOS, the presentModalViewController is obsolete and should be replaced with presentViewController, which I already did. Some posts also suggest about setting the delegate, which I also did. So let me explain what my app is doing and hopefully someone can help me please. :)

My app has been working alright, until iOS 5, I think.

I have a tabbed control. One of the tabs is my search which I use UISearchDisplayController. So in the text area, for example, one types "music" then in the table view below will display the entries that matches the search. The user will then click on one entry and I will present another view (showing details about that entry) using presentViewController (was presentModalViewController). This has been working until recently... it crashed!!! I have tried several things but none worked since some of the other scenarios mentioned in the other posts are different...

I logged the exception and it says exactly like this: "Application tried to present modally an active controller ."

The way I tested: I start the app. Click on the "Search" tab. Then type in something in the text area. A list of matched entries appear in the table. I click on one entry. At this time it should present another view, but it crashed and this is the error being logged.

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {} function, I created the detail view:

```
controller = [[SlaveReportPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlaveReportPageViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Then I call:

[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];

to launch it.

I appreciate any suggestion. Thank you.